# Issue regarding TouchesMoved using the method CGRectContainsPoint

Tags: ios, touchesmoved

My issue occurs when I drag the uiimageview accross the screen on, which is set to only be dragable in the x axis direction. 
The code sort of works. The uiimageview is moving alright and it's limited to the x axis only, which is exactly what it should. 
BUT when you start dragging outside the frame of the uiimageview, it stops moving along side my finger.

This obliviously has something to do with this method: CGRectContainsPoint.
Bare in mind it's very necessary in my code as I only want the uiimageview to move, when a user has set it's finger on it.

If I didn't use this method CGRectContainsPoint, the image would still move even when a users finger wouldn't touch the image. Any work around this is much appreciated.

here's my code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

NSLog(@"Touches Moved is running");

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

if (CGRectContainsPoint(UIImageView, location) && UIImageView >= 40)
{


    NSLog(@"Contains Point UIImageView Center!");

    CGPoint xLocation = CGPointMake(location.x,UIImageView);
    UIImageView = xLocation;

    //here it comes.. big block of code//
    if (location.x <= 40) {

        NSLog(@"Start Dragging Point");

        CGPoint newLocation = CGPointMake(40
                                          , 402);

        UIImageView = newLocation;
    }

    else if(location.x >= 273) {

        NSLog(@"End Dragging Point");

        CGPoint newLocation = CGPointMake(273
                                          , 402);

        UIImageView = newLocation;

    }
}
```

Comment: the issue is that whenever i drag the uiimageview and my finger reaches outside the uiimageview's frame it stops moving, when really it shouldn't. It should behave like the ios 6 slide to unlock home screen feature.

Answer (score 0):

Move `CGRectContainsPoint(UIImageView, location)` from `-(void)touchesMoved:...` to `-(void)touchesBegan:...`.

Set an ivar there that points to the view only when you began the touch inside the view. Use this ivar from `-(void)touchesMoved:...` to boundlessly move the view. You can then unset this variable both in `-(void)touchesEnded:...` and `-(void)touchesCancelled:...`.